# How to put the block diagram on the left side of the slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have created a  block diagram using Tikz package. Now where ever I run the block diagram comes in the middle. I want the block diagram to be placed on the left side so that I can use the right side for putting bullets about block diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% We need layers to draw the block diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define a few styles and constants
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{ann} = [above, text width=5em]
\tikzstyle{naveqs} = [sensor, text width=6em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=12em, rounded corners]
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (naveq) [naveqs] {Navigation equations};
    % Note the use of \path instead of \node at ... below. 
    \path (naveq.140)+(-\blockdist,0) node (gyros) [sensor] {Gyros};
    \path (naveq.-150)+(-\blockdist,0) node (accel) [sensor] {Accelero-meters};

    % Unfortunately we cant use the convenient \path (fromnode) -- (tonode) 
    % syntax here. This is because TikZ draws the path from the node centers
    % and clip the path at the node boundaries. We want horizontal lines, but
    % the sensor and naveq blocks aren't aligned horizontally. Instead we use
    % the line intersection syntax |- to calculate the correct coordinate
    \path [draw, ->] (gyros) -- node [above] {$\vc{\omega}_{ib}^b$} 
        (naveq.west |- gyros) ;
    % We could simply have written (gyros) .. (naveq.140). However, it's
    % best to avoid hard coding coordinates
    \path [draw, ->] (accel) -- node [above] {$\vc{f}^b$} 
        (naveq.west |- accel);
    \node (IMU) [below of=accel] {IMU};
    \path (naveq.south west)+(-0.6,-0.4) node (INS) {INS};
    \draw [->] (naveq.50) -- node [ann] {Velocity } + (\edgedist,0) 
        node[right] {$\vc{v}^l$};
    \draw [->] (naveq.20) -- node [ann] {Attitude} + (\edgedist,0) 
        node[right] { $\mx{R}_l^b$};
    \draw [->] (naveq.-25) -- node [ann] {Horisontal position} + (\edgedist,0)
        node [right] {$\mx{R}_e^l$};
    \draw [->] (naveq.-50) -- node [ann] {Depth} + (\edgedist,0) 
        node[right] {$z$};

    % Now it's time to draw the colored IMU and INS rectangles.
    % To draw them behind the blocks we use pgf layers. This way we  
    % can use the above block coordinates to place the backgrounds   
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % Compute a few helper coordinates
        \path (gyros.west |- naveq.north)+(-0.5,0.3) node (a) {};
        \path (INS.south -| naveq.east)+(+0.3,-0.2) node (b) {};
        \path[fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed]
            (a) rectangle (b);
        \path (gyros.north west)+(-0.2,0.2) node (a) {};
        \path (IMU.south -| gyros.east)+(+0.2,-0.2) node (b) {};
        \path[fill=blue!10,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed]
            (a) rectangle (b);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture

\end{document}
```

Now I have a block diagram, push this to left side and  put bullets on the space left  on right side.

Comment: I want to split the slide into two part. On the left side of the slide, I want to put a block diagram. And the right side of the slide I want to put phrases about block diagram.

Comment: So you are making a presentation? Why do you use `article` then? In fact, we can do that using `minipage`, etc.

Comment: I am using beamer  in my original code.

Comment: what is MWE? how it works

Comment: You already show it. That is [the compilable code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344) (minimal working example).

Answer (score 3):

Many of the values in your `tikzpicture` are hard coded. Because of this the picture does not scale well when inserted into a beamer frame. I propose to workaround this problem by compiling the diagram as a standalone picture and include this in the beamer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% We need layers to draw the block diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define a few styles and constants
\tikzset{sensor/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em}}
\tikzset{ann/.style={above, text width=5em}}
\tikzset{naveqs/.style={sensor, text width=6em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=12em, rounded corners}}
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}

\sffamily

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (naveq) [naveqs] {Navigation equations};
    % Note the use of \path instead of \node at ... below. 
    \path (naveq.140)+(-\blockdist,0) node (gyros) [sensor] {Gyros};
    \path (naveq.-150)+(-\blockdist,0) node (accel) [sensor] {Accelero-meters};

    % Unfortunately we cant use the convenient \path (fromnode) -- (tonode) 
    % syntax here. This is because TikZ draws the path from the node centers
    % and clip the path at the node boundaries. We want horizontal lines, but
    % the sensor and naveq blocks aren't aligned horizontally. Instead we use
    % the line intersection syntax |- to calculate the correct coordinate
    \path [draw, ->] (gyros) -- node [above] {$\vc{\omega}_{ib}^b$} 
        (naveq.west |- gyros) ;
    % We could simply have written (gyros) .. (naveq.140). However, it's
    % best to avoid hard coding coordinates
    \path [draw, ->] (accel) -- node [above] {$\vc{f}^b$} 
        (naveq.west |- accel);
    \node (IMU) [below of=accel] {IMU};
    \path (naveq.south west)+(-0.6,-0.4) node (INS) {INS};
    \draw [->] (naveq.50) -- node [ann] {Velocity } + (\edgedist,0) 
        node[right] {$\vc{v}^l$};
    \draw [->] (naveq.20) -- node [ann] {Attitude} + (\edgedist,0) 
        node[right] { $\mx{R}_l^b$};
    \draw [->] (naveq.-25) -- node [ann] {Horisontal position} + (\edgedist,0)
        node [right] {$\mx{R}_e^l$};
    \draw [->] (naveq.-50) -- node [ann] {Depth} + (\edgedist,0) 
        node[right] {$z$};

    % Now it's time to draw the colored IMU and INS rectangles.
    % To draw them behind the blocks we use pgf layers. This way we  
    % can use the above block coordinates to place the backgrounds   
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % Compute a few helper coordinates
        \path (gyros.west |- naveq.north)+(-0.5,0.3) node (a) {};
        \path (INS.south -| naveq.east)+(+0.3,-0.2) node (b) {};
        \path[fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed]
            (a) rectangle (b);
        \path (gyros.north west)+(-0.2,0.2) node (a) {};
        \path (IMU.south -| gyros.east)+(+0.2,-0.2) node (b) {};
        \path[fill=blue!10,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed]
            (a) rectangle (b);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{document2}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

an alternative:

- image in list are in table (`tabularx` environment wtih `c` and `X` column, by this is space for list equal `\textwidth` - image width)
- image is redrawn with goal to make it narrower (in this are considered small font size and `tikz` libraries `arrows.meta`, `backgrounds`, `fit`, `positioning`, quotes`;  code is little bit more sophisticated :-) )

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}

  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds, fit, positioning, quotes}% changed, new
  \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{back background}
  \pgfsetlayers{back background, background, main} % changed

  \usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
  \newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
  \newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command

  \usepackage{ragged2e} % new
  \usepackage{tabularx} % new

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{block diagram}
  {
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c>{\RaggedRight}X}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),
    node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
  F/.style 2 args = {draw, densely dashed, rounded corners=3pt,
                     fill=#1, fit=#2,
                     inner ysep=4mm, yshift=-2mm,
                     inner xsep=1mm},
    sensor/.style = {draw, fill=blue!40,
                     text width=4em, minimum height=5ex,
                     align=center},
  every edge quotes/.append style = {pos=0.55, align=center, inner sep=2pt,
                     font=\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
  every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb},
               font = \footnotesize
                          ]
  \node (sensor)  [sensor] {Gyros};
  \node (accel)   [sensor, below=of sensor] {Accelero-meters};
  %
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node (imu) [F={blue!20}{(sensor) (accel)},
               label={[anchor=south]below:IMU}] {};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
  \node (naveqtext)   [right=of imu, inner sep=0pt, align=center]     {Navigation\\equations};
  %
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node (naveq)   [F={red!20}{(sensor.north -| naveqtext.west) (accel.south -| naveqtext.east)}] {};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
  %
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{back background}
  \node (ins)     [F={yellow!30}{(imu) (naveq)},
                   label={[anchor=south]below:INS}] {};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
  %
      \begin{scope}[node distance=17mm],
  \node (out1) [right=of naveq.45 ] {$\vc{f}^b$};
  \node (out2) [right=of naveq.22 ] {$\mx{R}_l^b$};
  \node (out3) [right=of naveq.338] {$\mx{R}_e^l$};
  \node (out4) [right=of naveq.315] {$z$};
      \end{scope}
  \path   (sensor) edge ["$\vc{\omega}_{ib}^b$"]  (sensor -| naveq.west)
          (accel)  edge ["$\vc{f}^b$"]            (accel  -| naveq.west)
      (out1 -| naveq.east) edge ["Velocity"]              (out1)
      (out2 -| naveq.east) edge ["Attitude"]              (out2)
      (out3 -| naveq.east) edge ["Horisontal\\ position"] (out3)
      (out4 -| naveq.east) edge ["Depth"]                 (out4) ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
      &
  \begin{itemize}
      \item   item a
      \item   item b
      \item   item c
      \item   item d
      \item   item e
      \item   item f
  \end{itemize}
      \end{tabularx}
  }
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]